# What are the major differences in HTML 5 than previous versions?

Tags: xhtml, html

I want to ask what are the major things which HTML 5 have but previous version does not.
Every answer would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: yes i tried but not sufficient

Comment: You didn't try hard enough, then. I Googled **html5 vs html4** and got this huge paper from W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the html5 [specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html)?

Answer (score 1):

[html5 vs html4](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/) from w3.org